# Cron mail function with Content Type text/html

Tags: php, cron

There is possibility to add content type to cron command?

I'm doing something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /usr/home/login/domains/domain/public_html/cron/script.php > | mail -s "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" "topic" example@example.com
```

but its not working...

Comment: What are you getting in email?

Answer (score 2):

The -a option to the **mail** command allows specifying a header - you're passing the Content-Type as the subject argument. Try this:

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" -s "topic" example@example.com
```

Comment: still not working

`/usr/local/bin/php /usr/home/login/domains/domain/public_html/cron/script.php > | mail -a "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" -s "topic" example@example.com`